# CheckBox text to change based on its IsChecked

Tags: wpf, checkbox, triggers

I want a CheckBox text to changed based on the IsChecked status.

Tried with the following, but it complains about not having the property Content

```
                <CheckBox Name="IsManualInput" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsManual, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                    <CheckBox.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" >
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Manual" />
                                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" >
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Define manually..." />
                                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </CheckBox.Style>
                </CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple mistake, you need to include TargetType in your Style.

e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly it